# Copy content of an file "passwd" to an file userlist.txt

Tags: grep, passwd

The problem is that the file passwd hasn't got any tag like .txt or so.
So I can't copy the content by passed > userlist.txt.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you think it needs the extention `.txt` to be copied -- extensions have no meaning in Unix.

```
cp /etc/passwd userlist.txt
```

If you also care about LDAP/NIS/etc, and you have getent:

```
getent passwd > userlist.txt
```

Comment: I thougt it had a meaning because

Comment: cp /etc/passwd userlist.txt doesnt copy the content of the file ...

Comment: Write one line of shell code that
writes the contents of file /etc/passwd to "/root/results/userlist.txt" ... thats what I have to do :/

Comment: `cp /etc/passwd /root/results/userlist.txt` will do that, as long as `/root/results` exists.

Comment: Ok thanks you that worked. Can you say me how I can delete specific lines which contain "bin" in the file?

Comment: @user55167 Use `grep -v`, or `sed`. If you have another question, you should use the "Ask Question" link in the top right. This helps future readers.